# Can't download pyhash

Tags: python, path, command-prompt

I try to download pyhash with the command pip install pyhash in windows command prompt.This is the error I get:

```
    Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jaqtmq3t\pyhash_d67e02ac8dd9487ca69d147031402003\setup.py", line 38, in <module>
    os.path.join(os.environ.get('PYTHON_HOME'), 'include'),
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 76, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I have downloaded the latest version of pip and setuptools. Please help me, I am new to python and I don't know much